# Python, ftp to a path with spaces

Tags: python

I have a python script that makes backups to my QNAP.
QNAP from time to time changes the default name (visible via ftp) of the external drive.

In the new firmware it changed to `Seagate Expansion Drive`.

Now I need to correct the path in the config file:

`serverlocation = Seagate Expansion Drive/www03/config`

I tried:

```
serverlocation = "Seagate Expansion Drive"/www03/config
```

and

```
serverlocation = 'Seagate Expansion Drive'/www03/config
```

but still it says that the directory was not found on the ftp server.

The script uses that variable in this way:

```
try: ftp.mkd(self.config.get(jn, "serverlocation"))
                        except: pass
                    try: ftp.mkd("%s/%s" % (self.config.get(jn, "serverlocation"), self.date))
                    except: pass

syslog.syslog("Uploading %s..." % os.path.basename(location))
                        try:
                                th = FTPKeepalive(ftp)
                                th.start()
                                ftp.storbinary("STOR %s/%s/%s" % (self.config.get(jn, "serverlocation"), self.date, os.p>
                                th.alive = False
```

I am not a python developer, I am wondering how I can fix that path with spaces.

Comment: many times a space is replaced by a '+' in the actual URL that gets used (vs. the human readable version that you're seeing).  I would try Seagate+Expansion+Drive.

Comment: hmm still the same problem:

Uploading config.tar.7z...
`Error: unable to upload /root/ADMIN/BACKUP/config.tar.7z! Error: 550 Seagate+Expansion+Drive/www03/config/20210610_1647/config.tar.7z: No such file or directory`

Comment: The problem might be something other than the spaces in the name. Try removing the bare `except` clauses in/around the calls to `mkd()`. You might get an error message that points you to a solution. At present your call to `storbinary` is assuming the presence of the folder. If it isn't there, that is very likely because the `mkd()` is failing, and suppressing the error message just hides the problem. For example, you might lack permissions to create that directory.